# Можно ли вызвать async/await действия в @Html.Action()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Добрый день, господа! Есть необходимость вызвать дочерний action метод через `@Html.Action()` (речь идет об ASP.NET MVC). Можно ли так сделать? Код метода примерно следующий:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var products = await 
    _productsService.GetAll(CancellationToken.None);

      return PartialView(departments.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть мнение, что это приведёт к [проблемам](http://forums.asp.net/p/1823175/5062820.aspx). Ещё тут подробный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072720/async-partialview-causes-httpserverutility-execute-blocked-exception). [Объяснения](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601) все, как водится, на английском.

Краткая суть, насколько я её понимаю, в том, что асинхронным может быть только корневое действие, дочерние делать асинхронными нельзя.

Однако, как заметил @andreycha есть некий [ASP.NET vNext](https://habrahabr.ru/post/242243/) (сейчас это называется ASP.NET Core) в котором асинхронность поддерживается более целостно при помощи [View Components](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/exciting-things-about-asp-net-vnext-series-mvc-view-components), которые полностью заменяют `child action`.

Выглядит это очень просто:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    var profileLinks = await _profileLinkManager.GetAllAsync();            
    return View(profileLinks);
}
```

Более полное описание с примерами есть [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/7.6.php).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: В последней приведенной вами ссылке написано, что это уже пофикшено.

Comment: @andreycha Не то, чтобы пофиксено. Предлагается использовать некий ASP.NET vNext MVC и его View Components для реализации асинхронности в дочерних действиях. Добавляю это явно в свой ответ, спасибо.